# File sharing under Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, file-upload, download

I am a Java EE newbie, and I am asked to create a File sharing application.

Could anyone help me to find some sort of a library or a framework that would help me handle the file download and upload?

The file storage is supposed to be in a database (not a file system).
I am really sorry if the question was asked before, but I don't understand the search results I get from google (since I am new to Java EE).

Comment: Thanks for the edit Arjan Tijms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a solution (only if you are using PrimeFaces) :

- file upload [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)
- file download [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml)

File download is pretty straight forward. You will need 'Apache Commons io' and 'Apache Commons File Upload' libraries and some filter configurations to do in your web.xml for the upload.